I'm having difficulty identifying a union and I wish to disassemble this gas line
I'd like to replace this reducer after the regulator with a reducing tee so I can run another line to a gas fire pit.  The concern is I don't want to attempt to break this open until I am certain how to disassemble it.  is component between the regulator and the coupling a union?  Anything else I should know before trying to remove this?


There is no union there that I can see. Just pipe fittings, which simply unscrew in the usual way. Looks like you will be cutting pipe somewhere.

is there enough capacity to allow the additional burner?

Listen man, take this advice from someone who does his own mechanical work on trucks, all electrical and plumbing in my house, and never, ever call someone to fix anything for me. Get a licensed plumber to work with gas fittings.

You may have a left-right coupling and nipple down below the regulator.  Look very closely at the exposed threads on the nipples above and below the coupling - if it's a left-right set there will be standard threads on one piece and left-hand threads on the other.  If so, turning the coupling one direction will loosen both sides while turning it the other direction will tighten both sides.  https://www.plumbingsupply.com/leftright.html

@Cheery, As someone who could relate to never trusting a mechanic with my own vehicles;  Someone who rarely calls an electrician unless it is to say "Sign the permit, my work is more clean than yours anyway"; and someone who has plumbed entire houses, electrical and gas.  Are you saying you wouldn't do it yourself?

@jsotola Regarding capacity, what do you mean exactly?  I have a 1000 gallon propane tank that I refill 2x per year and it fluctuates between 100-150 psi.  The fire pit I'm teeing off of this line needs 0.5 PSI and will probably run for 100-200 hours/year.  I can't see this making a considerable difference.
